# How to automatically insert DatePicker upon adding new table row?

Tags: microsoft-word

Scenario: I have a Microsoft Word template with a table in it. The table has a column "date", in which the template has the DatePicker element.

Problem: Upon adding a new table row e.g. by pressing tab in the last cell (the table can have various numbers of rows in the final document emerging from the template), the "date" column is empty instead of having a DatePicker in it.

How can I achive automatic insertion of the DatePicker? Is there a way to have one row of the template be a "template row" for all the rows which are to be added?